# Suppressing a Trigger Send Definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk

What is the prototypical way to suppress certain users from a Triggered Send Definition via the API?

It seems there are two ways to suppress a TriggeredSendDefinition:

1. exclusionListCollections - are not supported in the Fuelsdk?
2. exclusionFilters - need specials permissions (SEND_TIME_FILTERING   business rule, which you seem to need to contact ET in order to set?)

Am I confusing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not just skip the API call?

If that's not option, an exclusion script (aka Audience Exclusion Script) is the typical way to suppress triggered emails at send time.

Here's [an example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/72644/5202) for a User-Initiated Send, but the same can be done in a Triggered Send Definition.  Another [another example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/96530/5202).

Don't wear yourself out trying to create a Triggered Send Definition via API.  Create it in the interface, configure your exclusion script and then just execute a triggered send via API.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to be able to create these triggered send definitions programmatically. However the special permissions is not to much of an issue, Thanks!

Comment: TSDs should typically be a one-off type of thing, unless you're building some sort of migration utility.  I've encountered plenty people trying to create a bunch of TSDs when creating User-Initiated Sends is much more appropriate.